# Create a saved search (.search-ms) from terms in Explorer search box

Tags: c#, search

Is there some C# code for creating saved query files (.search-ms) from search terms entered in the Explorer search box in the same way that ISearchQueryHelper expands search terms into OLEDB queries for the Windows Search API? Or code for converting the OLEDB queries into a .search-ms file? I would like to show results from a Windows search in Explorer - I could display the OleDb query results in a grid but would much prefer to use Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that creating a saved search and then running it is not the easiest way of launching a Windows/File explorer window showing filtered results, as the saved search XML is very complex to generate programmatically. Taking the contents of the box to the left of search box as a URL and supplying it to *Internet* Explorer gives the right results.

After entering the search string

```
name:~ "*[*2602_Australia_Australian Capital Territory_Downer*].*" OR  name:~ "*[*2602_Australia_Australian Capital Territory_O'Connor*].*"
```

in the folder

```
C:\Users\Simon\Pictures\iPhoneSample
```

The expected results are shown. Clicking on the left hand box showing "Search Results in iPhoneSample" shows:

```
search-ms:displayname=Search%20Results%20in%20iPhoneSample&crumb=name%3A~"*[*2602_Australia_Australian%20Capital%20Territory_Downer*].*"%20OR%20name%3A~"*[*2602_Australia_Australian%20Capital%20Territory_O'Connor*].*"&crumb=location:C%3A%5CUsers%5CSimon%5CPictures%5CiPhoneSample
```

Supplying this as URL to *Internet* Explorer (iexplore.exe rather than Explorer.exe) shows a new  Windows/File Explorer window with the expected search results. Some C# code for doing this is shown below:

```
/// <summary>
    ///  Show Windows Explorer in new window with results filtered by search string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sCommonFolder">Folder to search in </param>
    /// <param name="sSearchString">search string</param>
    private void ShowSearchResultsInExplorer(string sCommonFolder, string sSearchString)
    {
       // sCmd = "search-ms:displayname=Search%20Results%20in%20iPhoneSample&crumb=name" & _
        //"%3A~""*[*2602_Australia_Australian%20Capital%20Territory_Downer*].*""%20OR%20name%3A~""" & _
        //"*[*2602_Australia_Australian%20Capital%20Territory_O'Connor*].*""&crumb=location:C%3A%5CUsers%5CSimon%5CPictures%5CiPhoneSample"

        string sFilter = "search-ms:displayname=";
        sFilter +=  Uri.EscapeDataString("Tagged files in "  + sCommonFolder);
        sFilter += @"&crumb=" +sSearchString;
        sFilter += @"&crumb=location:" + Uri.EscapeDataString(sCommonFolder);

        Process.Start("IExplore.exe", sFilter);

    }
```

After displaying search results, the window needs to be closed before displaying subsequent search results, otherwise the subsequent results are not displayed. This can be done with the following code:

```
SHDocVw.ShellWindows shellWindows = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows();

        foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer window in shellWindows)
        {
            Console.Write ("Window " + window.LocationName  + " " + window.LocationURL + " " + window.Name + " " + window.HWND + "\r\n");
            if (window.LocationName.Contains("Tagged files"))
            {                   
                SendMessage((IntPtr)window.HWND, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            }
        }
```

This code requires a few declarations:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
....
static uint WM_CLOSE = 0x10;
 ...
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```